# Sinch - Group messaging in Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, sinch

Our team is looking to use Sinch in an ongoing project, however we can't find anything on group messaging. Is this currently supported? The targeted platforms are Android and iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Using Sinch, you can currently send messages to groups of 10 participants maximum. See https://www.sinch.com/docs/ios/user-guide/#instantmessaging (Sending a message to multiple recipients) for more information.

Comment: Can Anyone tell how to maintain chat history of group members participating in group?: Android